# Using jquery .when with multiple animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i'm new to jquery and to js so maybe it is a stupid question.

I have two animations:

```
$(foo2).fadeOut(1000);
$(foo1).fadeOut(2000);
```

and i want a callback called when they have finished **in some elegant way (scalable to any number of animation with different - and not known duration - possibly using .when)**

till now i call `.when` only in the longest animation:

```
function different_animation() {

  effect = function() {

   foo1 = 'div'; //this is an example that selects multiple elements
   foo2 = 'p'; //this is an example that selects multiple elements

    var ret1 = $(foo1).fadeOut(1000);
    var ret2 = $(foo2).fadeOut(2000);

    var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log('fade out at'+seconds);

    // i know that to ret2 there is attached a longer animation is longer then ret1
    return ret2; 
  }

  $.when( effect() ).done(function() {
    var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log('done at '+seconds);
  });
}
```

but what if there are more animation and i don't know the timing of each ones? i need something that could join the rets.

Comment: IMO, $.what is not any sort of elegant way. It's like syntax sugar for jQuery and it sorta ruins event-oriented paradigm. You could just use Event.js or write your own event subscribe/publish factory and do it like bees: $(foo2).fadeOut(2000, onRet2AnimationDone); onRet2AnimationDone(function () { alert("DONE"); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and the callback functionality of `fadeOut`:

```
var deferred1 = $.Deferred();
var deferred2 = $.Deferred();
$(foo1).fadeOut(1000, function() { deferred1.resolve(); } );
$(foo2).fadeOut(2000, function() { deferred2.resolve(); } );

$.when(deferred1, deferred2).done(function() {
    console.log("both animations have completed");
});
```

This can easily scale to any number of animations (and promises in general). You can place as many promises or deferreds into an array and use

```
$.when.apply(null, arrayOfPromises).done(callback);
```

to fire `callback` when all of them are completed.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/2sJVX/)**.

Answer (score 2):

The `.animate()` and other effect methods of jQuery returns an object usable in the `.when()` method, so it's not necessary to manually create and resolve the deferred objects.

```
var promises = [];
promises.push($("#foo1").fadeOut(1000));
promises.push($("#foo2").fadeOut(2000));
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() { /* all done */ });
```

As can be seen in this version of Jons jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2sJVX/55/

Answer (score 1):

According [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) of `jquery.Deferred()`, you can chain your functions into the array, something like this:

```
var arrayOfAnimation = [];

effect = function() {

  foo1 = 'div'; //this is an example that selects multiple elements
  foo2 = 'p'; //this is an example that selects multiple elements

  var deferred1 = $.Deferred();
  var deferred2 = $.Deferred();
  $(foo1).fadeOut(1000, function() { deferred1.resolve(); } );
  $(foo2).fadeOut(2000, function() { deferred2.resolve(); } );

  arrayOfAnimation.push(deferred1);
  arrayOfAnimation.push(deferred2);

  var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  console.log('fade out at'+seconds);
}

$.done(arrayOfAnimation)
.done()
.done(function() {
  var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  console.log('done at '+seconds);
});
```

**Update:**
Example from docs:

```
<script>
/* 3 functions to call when the Deferred object is resolved */
function fn1() {
  $("p").append(" 1 ");
}
function fn2() {
  $("p").append(" 2 ");
}
function fn3(n) {
  $("p").append(n + " 3 " + n);
}

/* create a deferred object */
var dfd = $.Deferred();

/* add handlers to be called when dfd is resolved */
dfd
/* .done() can take any number of functions or arrays of functions */
.done( [fn1, fn2], fn3, [fn2, fn1] )
/* we can chain done methods, too */
.done(function(n) {
  $("p").append(n + " we're done.");
});

/* resolve the Deferred object when the button is clicked */
$("button").bind("click", function() {
  dfd.resolve("and");
});
</script>
```

Comment: is it scalable to any number of animations?